# Rails recyclable cache keys not working (still contains cache_version)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 5.2 app that's configured to use the new much touted feature of **recyclable cache keys**.

I can confirm the setting is enabled in the console:

```
Rails.application.config.active_record.cache_versioning
=> true

ActiveRecord::Base.cache_versioning
=> true

BlogPost.cache_versioning
=> true
```

With this setting, `blog_post.cache_key` now returns a stable string, because the `cache_version` is actually stored inside the cache entry (as [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/cache-invalidation-complexity-rails-52-and-dalli-c) details):

```
blog_post.cache_key
=> "blog_posts/10317"

blog_post.cache_version
=> "20190417193345000000"
```

But the problem is, even tough everything works as expected in the console, I can't seem to see this working watching the server logs, because it keeps generating cache_keys that contain the cache_version:

```
In my view:

<% cache(['blog_post_list_item_v2', blog_post, I18n.locale, browser.device.mobile?]) do %>
  ...
<% end %>

In the server logs:

Rendered blog/blog_posts/_blog_post_list_item.html.erb (2.5ms) [cache miss]
Read fragment views/blog/blog_posts/_blog_post_list_item:0bdff42a9193ea497e5ed4a9cc2f51e8/blog_post_list_item_v2/blog_posts/10317-20190417193345000000/pt-br/ (0.5ms)
```

As you see, the cache key should be `.../blog_posts/10317/`, but it actually contains the timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

After debugging through the Rails code, I could confirm that the `key` was actually stable. What gets printed in the server log includes the version for debugging purposes only, but the key being stored on your cache doesn't actually contain the version.

The version is stored instead within the serialized object in the cache, which is an instance of `ActiveSupport::Cache::Entry` and contains an `attr_reader :version`. So, if you're like me, you'd assume that the cache (for instance, raw HTML) was stored directly in memcached, but it actually is stored in the `value` attribute of that `ActiveSupport::Cache::Entry` (which also has the `version` attribute if you have `cache_versioning` turned on), and that entire object is saved serialized into the cache.

If you want to confirm it yourself, you can check your own memcached realtime log. If you're on a mac, first stop it (I'm assuming it was installed with homebrew) with `brew services stop memcached`, start it on the foreground with verbose mode with `memcached -vv` and take a look at the keys requested by rails. After you finish your study, `brew services start memcached` will re-enable memcached as a daemon.

Also, if you are migrating from the old way (without recyclable cache keys), you should wipe your cache first with `Rails.cache.clear` in the console. Remember to do that in production as well.

If you want to understand more about how this works, a good read is `https://dzone.com/articles/cache-invalidation-complexity-rails-52-and-dalli-c`, but debugging through the rails code with `binding.pry` was what got things clear to me.

In a nutshell, it's a very brilliant implementation in my opinion, and the cache recycling just makes it so much better (the article quotes DHH saying that 'We went from only being able to keep 18 hours of caching to, I believe, 3 weeks. It was the single biggest performance boost that Basecamp 3 has ever seen.')